# UITableView: how to disable dragging of items to a specific row?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView with draggable rows and I can add/remove items. The datasource is a NSMutableArray.

Now, if I move the row with "Add new functionality" the app crashes because the dataSource is smaller since such row has not been added yet.

So I've modified this code:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        if (indexPath.row >= [dataList count]) return NO;
        return YES;
    }
```

And now I can't move it anymore. However I can still move the other rows after such row and consequently the code crashes.

How can I solve this ? Is there a way to disable the dragging **"to"** specific rows and not only from ?

thanks

Comment: Is there a way to prevent moving for all rows instead of just one?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This is exactly what the `UITableViewDelegate` method

`-tableView:targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:toProposedIndexPath:`

is for.  Will it suit your purposes?  [Here's](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614953-tableview) the documentation.

Answer (score 27):

The previous answers and the documentation (see [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageReorderRow/ManageReorderRow.html) and [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:toProposedIndexPath:), as mentioned in the other answers) are helpful but incomplete.  I needed:

- examples
- to know what to do if the proposed move is not okay

Without further ado, here are some

### Examples

#### Accept all moves

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath
                         toProposedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)proposedDestinationIndexPath
{
    return proposedDestinationIndexPath;
}
```

#### Reject all moves, returning the row to its initial position

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath
                         toProposedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)proposedDestinationIndexPath
{
    return sourceIndexPath;
}
```

#### Reject some moves, returning any rejected row to its initial position

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath
                         toProposedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)proposedDestinationIndexPath
{
    if (... some condition ...) {
        return sourceIndexPath;
    }
    return proposedDestinationIndexPath;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton @Matt
+1 Vote (Y)

Answer (score 9):

How to make last row fix:

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath
       toProposedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)proposedDestinationIndexPath
{
    // get number of objects
    NSUInteger numberOfObjects = [[[BNRItemStore sharedStore] allItems] count]; 

    if ( (proposedDestinationIndexPath.row+1==numberOfObjects) || (sourceIndexPath.row+1==numberOfObjects) ) {
        NSLog(@"HERE");
        return sourceIndexPath;
    }
    else{
         NSLog(@"count=%d %d", [[[BNRItemStore sharedStore] allItems] count], proposedDestinationIndexPath.row);
        return proposedDestinationIndexPath;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Following is the example to restrict drag and drop to 0th index of 1st section `UICollectionView`:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, dropSessionDidUpdate session: UIDropSession, withDestinationIndexPath destinationIndexPath: IndexPath?) -> UICollectionViewDropProposal {

    if session.localDragSession != nil {
        // Restricts dropping to 0th index
        if destinationIndexPath?.row == 0 {
           return UICollectionViewDropProposal(operation: .forbidden) 
        }

        if collectionView.hasActiveDrag {
            return UICollectionViewDropProposal(operation: .move, intent: .insertAtDestinationIndexPath)
        } else {
            return UICollectionViewDropProposal(operation: .copy, intent: .insertAtDestinationIndexPath)
        }
    }        
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, itemsForBeginning session: UIDragSession, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UIDragItem] {
    // Prevents dragging item from 0th index
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        return [UIDragItem]() // Prevents dragging item from 0th index
    }

    let item = self.yourArray[indexPath.row]
    let itemProvider = NSItemProvider(object: item)
    let dragItem = UIDragItem(itemProvider: itemProvider)
    dragItem.localObject = item
    return [dragItem]
}
```

Comment: `return [UIDragItem]()` to prevent dragging for certain cells was exactly what I was looking for! THANK YOU!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Following is the working solution for disable row from moving.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        if indexPath.row == 0{//specify your indexpath row here....
            return false
        }else{
            return true
        }
        
    }
```