# How do you make it so you can't drag a specific cell in a UICollectionView in Swift 3 iOS 11 and above?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, drag-and-drop, ios11

I have a collection view with a few spaces. The spaces can be filled with profile photos. I made the empty spaces have a button that triggers adding a photo. I made it so the uploaded photos can be dragged and dropped by making the view controller that manages the collection view conform to the `UICollectionViewDragDelegate` and `UICollectionViewDropDelegate` protocols. How do I make it so the empty spaces cannot be dragged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the collectionView `itemsForBeginning` method of the `UICollectionViewDragDelegate`, write logic to drag the cells you want to drag and then end with

```
else {
   return [UIDragItem]()
 }
```

and then cells that fall to the else will not be draggable.

reference for my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52183966/8441431

(^^^They were answering a different question)